# why major chords only have 1-3-5 notes why not other notes?

Tags: guitar, theory, chord-theory

I have gone through this question

> The chord formula for the Major Chord is 1- 3 - 5. What do the numbers represent?
>   I haven't understand that and I have also read many document.

Please can any one make me understand in layman language.

> I know that chromatic scales work on 12 notes.
>   major scale work on octave formula(W-W-H-W-W-W-H)
>   chords represent 1-3-5 . 1 notes ,3 notes, and 5 notes of C major scales.
>   but why 1-3-5 only why not other notes
>   Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The major chord is made from notes 1,3 and 5 of a major scale. Fact. The root note is 1, the next is the 3rd, 4 semitones higher, and the 5th is 3 semitones higher than that. They blend well together. Try other mixes, and while some will sound harmonious, by and large, particularly in the Western world, this major chord - a blend of those three notes, has become well accepted. There may be scientific reasons why they blend well, but the fact is, they do.Harmonics come into the equation, but don't come up with an absolute reason.By adding other notes, it stops being just a major chord, so three is the best number of notes. Two can be construed as a chord (by some), but often it's not enough to give a complete blend that we're used to.

Comment: Not sure why it was down voted. I think this is a good explanation which addresses the importance of intervals (gave +1 for this). Yes we do have major 7 chords but i think it is beyond the scope of the quoted sentences above. Besides they have different sounds compared to the major triads, as the maj7 chords contain a minor chord in them. Eg. C maj7= C E G B which contains E G B, an E minor chord.

Comment: it is important to note that notes 1,3,5 that @Tim mention here are not necessarily the same as do, mi, sol. It simply means the root or starting note, then the third above the root, and fifth above the root.